# How to format Oracle date and timestamp type values in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, simpledateformat

I have date and timestamp type fields in oracle db, I need to retrieve these values and map them to my object field. Though I format the values I do not get the expected result. Here is the my code snippet.

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Operation{
private Date created;
private Date valueDate;

public Date getValueDate() {
    return this.valueDate;
}
public void setValueDate(Date valueDate) {
this.valueDate = valueDate;
}
public Date getCreated() {
    return this.valueDate;
}
public void setCreated(Date created) {
this.created= created;
}
}


//here starts code snippet to call db method

SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

String formatCreated = df1.format(result.getTimestamp(22)); //Input from db: 23-FEB-18 06.17.42.302680 PM 
//OutputFormat 2018-02-23 18:17:42.000302  
String formatValueDate = df2.format(result.getTimestamp(23));//Input from db:23.02.2018 18:17:42 
//OutputFormat 2018-02-23 18:17:42
Operation op = new Operartion();
op.setCreated(df1.parse(formatCreated)) //Output Fri Feb 23 18:17:42 GMT+04:00 2018
op.setCreated(df1.parse(formatValuedate)) //Output Fri Feb 23 18:17:42 GMT+04:00 2018
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you are at least at Java 8, consider using the new Date/Time API instead.

Comment: So formatCreated doesn't show milliseconds, but parsing it returns them?

Comment: @Axel no i don't,  jrev6 is used in the project

Comment: OK then. What do you really want to do? `op.setCreated(result.getTimestamp(22))`?

Comment: @Axel, My apologies, pls see my updates  on inputs/outputs. I have commented them out

Comment: But both inputs are the same. There's a different format set on the database, but that doesn't matter because you call getTimestamp(). No formatting is involved here. And then you store Date Objects, not Strings. Date objects don't have a format, so the output you see is what should be expected. So it is unclear what you really want to achieve. If i.e. getValuedate should return the date in a special format, you'd have to return String, not Date. Otherwise it would be the caller's responsibility to apply the correct format.

Comment: @Axel yes, what I want to achieve to getCreated() and getValueDate methods returns date objects in the the format I parsed them while setting to the object _op_. You say it's not possible if i return date object but  .parse(String obj) method is for returning date objects in the special format. Then why it is impossible?

Comment: @devgirl No, the parse(String) method is not for returning date objects in the specified format. It is for parsing a string with the specified format into a Date object. For your problem, there are several solutions. You could for example add a method `getDateCreatedAsString()` that formats the date and returns a String. But Whatever solution is the right one depends on how your model is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search before posting.

So briefly…

## Use *java.time*

Use modern *java.time* classes, rather than the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date`/`Calendar`.

### Use smart objects, not dumb strings

As of JDBC 4.2, exchange *java.time* objects directly with the database.

- Use `Instant` for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`
- Use `LocalDateTime` for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`
- Use `LocalDate` for `DATE`

Call `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Note that no strings were used at all.

> //Input from db: 23-FEB-18 06.17.42.302680 PM

Incorrect. Your assumption is false. The database uses its own internally-defined binary format to store date-time values, not strings/text. Do not conflate date-time values with their textual representations. In other words, date-time values do not have a “format”.

## Strings

Generate strings in standard ISO 8601 format by calling `toString` on the java.time objects.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

For other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `SimpleDateFormat`. Already covered well on Stack Overflow, so search.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am well informed about java.time API,but since jre v6 is used in the project, I do not have this option. So any suggestion that would work with jre v6?

Comment: @devgirl For Java 6, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* library. See the last bullets in my Answer.  The back-port’s API mirrors *java.time* as much as possible. Later, when you eventually update to Java 8 or later, you’ll need do little more than change your `import` statements to phase out the back-port. Well worth the bother of adding a library dependency to your project; the legacy date-time classes are a wretched mess and should be avoided.