# Oracle jdbc driver throwing error on a supported mapping type

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, localdate, java-time

I am using this oracle driver: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html

I have jdk8 installed. According to oracle: my driver is JDBC 4.2 compliant

[image: compliance]

Also, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49073531/5145783
my code should work.

```
myCallableStatement.setObject("p_pr_submitted_date", myLocalDate, Types.DATE);
```

or

```
myCallableStatement.setObject("p_pr_submitted_date", myLocalDate);
```

But, I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid conversion requested

and/or

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Here too, it mentions this mapping is supported: https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr221/JDBC4.2MR-January2014.pdf

Why do I get this error? Is my driver not correct?

Comment: Try using the latest version of `ojdbc8.jar`, i.e. the **19.3** version.

Comment: Maybe it's because Oracle doesn't have the equivalent of a LocalDate? Did you try `setObject("....", myLocalDate, Types.TIMESTAMP)`?

Comment: What does your procedure look like in Oracle SQL? Which SQL type is it expecting/requiring?